# identifier 'SYS.DBMS_SQL' must be declared error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is my package body. But getting identifier 'SYS.DBMS_SQL' must be declared error and 'SYS.DBMS_LOB' must be declared error.I am using global temporary table to insert data into it and then using it to delete records from a table.

```
 procedure del_cop (p_in_del_cri_mos in number,
                     p_out_err_msg    out varchar2,
                     p_dop            in number default 1
                    ) is
  begin
    if  xxau_house_keep_globals.g_batch_id is null
    then
        xxau_house_keep_globals.g_batch_id := xxau_housekeeplog_batch_id_seq.nextval;
    end if;
execute immediate 'truncate table to_del_cnf_pye_bse_gtt';
insert into to_del_cnf_pye_bse_gtt (fap_inr_idr, cpb_rowid)
      select cpb.fap_inr_idr,
             cpb.rowid
      from   to_cnf_pye_bse_test cpb
      where  cpb.lod_tmp < (systimestamp - numtoyminterval(nvl(p_in_del_cri_mos,15), 'MONTH'));
commit;
delete from to_cop_msg_aud_test
    where fap_inr_idr in (select fap_inr_idr from to_del_cnf_pye_bse_gtt gtt);
commit;
exception
    when others then
      rollback;
end del_cop;
```

Comment: Packages `DBMS_SQL` and `DBMS_LOB` are basic packages in Oracle server. Without these packages your database does not work at all. By default EXECUTE privilege is granted to PUBLIC.

Comment: You code does not contain any `DBMS_SQL` but as already mentioned it is a basic package and used internally by other functions. Did you "gamble" with your database at took it out of order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing privileges on those packages. Let `SYS` grant `EXECUTE` privilege **directly** to you (not via role) because such privileges won't work in named PL/SQL procedures (and yours *is* a *named* procedure, is it not? Its name is `del_cop` which is part of (also named) package).

Comment: But due to which reason or part of my code is it accessing those packages?

Comment: This part isn't. But, as you said, it is part of a **package**. You can't compile it if there's something wrong and - apparently - there is.

Comment: The package is complied and there is nothing else apart from this procedure inside it. I am getting this error during running the procedure

Comment: OK. To cut a long story short: did you (or did not) grant privileges directly to user which is running this procedure?

Comment: Packages `DBMS_SQL` and `DBMS_LOB` are one the very(!) basic packages, by default EXECUTE privilege is granted to PUBLIC.

Comment: What do you think, what is going on here, @Wernfried?

Comment: Maybe something stupid, e.g. `DROP ROLE PUBLIC` due to exaggerated security concerns.

Comment: I see, @Wernfried. Hm, I'd really like to know what caused that. Maybe EXECUTE on those packages was **revoked** from PUBLIC (also because of security concerns)?

Comment: NB, your answer almost is correct. Privileges in PL/SQL need to be granted **directly**, not via a ROLE -  unless for role `PUBLIC`! Privileges granted to role `PUBLIC` also apply inside PL/SQL packages, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-41D23DE7-3C07-41CF-962B-F92B696594B5

Comment: Aha. Thank you for that, @Wernfried, I'll try to remember it.

Comment: Well, in 99% of all cases you can ignore this fact.